# Wrap Swift library for use from Python on MacOS

Tags: python, swift, wrapper

Most of the questions here go about "how to I use Python in Swift". I want to do the opposite: use a Swift library from Python on Mac OS.

I have a library in Swift that performs fast calculations on GPU using Metal Performance Shaders. I want wrap that code so it is callable from Python (restricted to MacOS only is fine) and pass some Numpy matrices from Python to Swift, let swift do calculations, and return the resulting Numpy matrices back. If it's not possible to pass the Numpy matrices, I guess I could live with passing in the arrays. Is there a way to achieve this kind of interop?

Comment: Wacky that nobody has chimed in. Python and Numpy (and the vast body of Numpy-based libraries) are a formidable combination for scientific computing and machine learning. That with a Swift-based user experience is where it's at. Anybody? … Beuller?

Comment: I’m asking for the opposite actually. Calling a Swift library from Python.

Comment: Have you seen https://gist.github.com/jiaaro/02c7cdacf3cb6fd6648464491d6c5964 ?